# Can the loop parameter be accessed in implicit loops during vectorization?

Tags: r, vector

I have a question for R gurus out there. I'll illustrate it on the following example:

I have a vector, say 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
I'd like to get a vector of sums of 2 elements: 3,5,7,9,11,13,15

This is just an example, I'm not looking for a trick, I want to do it with just vectorization and indexing. Is there any way to get access to the implicit loop parameter as it goes through it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, so some people asked for the actual example. That makes sense. Here we go.

There is a matrix. For each element of the matrix I would like to get a sum of 4 elements of the matrix that are positioned on the lines parallel to the diagonals of the matrix and go through this element. Depending on the value of the element, they would go bottom left for 1, bottom right for 2, top left for 3 and top right for 4.

Comment: Edit your question to provide the input as an R object and show the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rollapply` from zoo package

```
> x <- 1:8
> rollapply(x, width=2, FUN=sum)
[1]  3  5  7  9 11 13 15
```

Comment: That would belong to the trick category. This is just an example, in a more complex real life situation, where there is a data frame and you need parts of it in the loop that won't work.

Comment: @user3208049 Post a reproducible example that shows your problem for we to better understand your problem/question and try to give an answer

Comment: @user3208049 Why don't you provide an example that actually illustrates your real problem, then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` or a variation of it, and write a function that sums up appropriate elements given the indexes, and your matrix. For example,

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
m
```

Create a data frame with all possible index pairs

```
m_ind <- expand.grid(1:nrow(m),1:ncol(m), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(m_ind) <- c("i","j")
m_ind
m[as.matrix(m_ind[,1:2])]
```

Diagonals, or the parallel lines can be described by constant diffs, or constant sums of the indexes

```
m_ind$dif_ij <- m_ind$i - m_ind$j
m_ind$sum_ij <- m_ind$i + m_ind$j
```

Then sum up the elements you want

```
m_ind$sum1 <- sapply(1:nrow(m_ind), function(k, mydf, colname, mymatr) 
          sum(mymatr[as.matrix(mydf[mydf[, colname]==mydf[k, colname], c("i","j")])]),mydf=m_ind, colname="dif_ij", mymatr=m)
m_ind$sum2 <- sapply(1:nrow(m_ind), function(k, mydf, colname, mymatr)
          sum(mymatr[as.matrix(mydf[mydf[, colname]==mydf[k, colname], c("i","j")])]), mydf=m_ind, colname="sum_ij", mymatr=m)
```

and, finally combine them

```
m_ind$sum <- m_ind$sum1 + m_ind$sum2
m_ind
```